# Updating a row in parse table using the object Id of the current device

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi I am trying to update the location of the current device into the parse database using the `objectId` of this device.

```
        ParseQuery innerQuery = new ParseQuery("_Installation");
        innerQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation());//current phone
        ParseQuery<PhoneFinder> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(PhoneFinder.class);
        query.whereMatchesQuery("identification", innerQuery);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<PhoneFinder>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<PhoneFinder> list, ParseException e) {
                for (PhoneFinder loc : list)
                {
                    loc.setLocation(geoPoint);
                    loc.saveInBackground();
                }
            }
        });
```

If I use the `objectId` explicitly is works fine.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You said you have a solution that "works fine", so what is your question?

Comment: @nasch How can I make it work when I use `ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation())`  instead of the value of the `objectId`. The idea is the get the value of the `objectId` of the current installation, and update the location using where the`objectId` is the same

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what's wrong with the code you posted (that is, exactly what it does wrong) but I'm going to guess `innerQuery` doesn't return any rows.  If that is the case, this information from the API docs may help:

Note: We only allow the following types of queries for installations:

```
query.get(objectId)
 query.whereEqualTo("installationId", value)
 query.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("installationId", keyInQuery, query)
```

`whereEqualTo("objectId",value)` isn't on that list, so that is probably why it's not working.  Also, `ParseInstallation.getQuery` is the best way to get a query to use for installations.